# need to check if a string is present. if not, write it to the text file

Tags: regex, string, perl

Trying to write to a text file that has a list of names and serial numbers. each one will be on a separate line. if the name:::number is there already, it shouldn't write it, but it can't seem to find one that's already there, so it rewrites it. Here is my code:

```
$regfile = "REG/reglist.txt";
$find = $name.":::".$serial."\n";
$index = 0;

open(REG,">>$regfile") or fail();

my @line = <REG>;

foreach $line (@lines) {
    if ($line eq $find) {
        $index++;
    } 
}

if ($index == 0) {
    print REG "$find";
} else { 
    print REG "was already there.\n"; 
}

close(REG);
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: You are trying to read from a file that you opened in append mode...

Comment: @Onyambu: Check the tags on the question

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 4):

You should handle two files

First one, for read purposes (`$fh_reg` on "REG/reglist.txt"). Note the '<' read mode:

```
open my $fh_reg, '<', "REG/reglist.txt" or die $!;
```

Second one, is a temporary file (`$fh_temp`) used to write the desired output. The [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) module may help you a lot:

```
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;
# ...
my ($fh_temp, $filename_temp) = tempfile();
```

And finally, [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) this file as the first one.

```
rename $filename_temp, "REG/reglist.txt";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read from a file handle `REG` that you have opened for output

You are also reading into array `@line` and then working with the contents of `@lines`

You *must always*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
```

at the top of every Perl program you write

Comment: When I use "use strict;" I get an internal server error every time so I can't use it for some reason. Is something not installed for this? "use warnings 'all'; did not do anything on its own. the program ran but without the right output.

Comment: @user:  You didn't mention that this is a CGI app! The "internal server error" is because your program is invalid with `use strict` in place and it just dies during compilation. That's a good thing! Read your server log (or `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)` or just run your program from the command line) to reveal the errors that it has uncovered. It will probably be a missing declaration. *Never* remove `use strict` to get your program working: it is counter-productive.

Comment: there is too much info being passed from the web form to do it via command line. adding **use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)** also causes an internal server error. didn't know it made a difference that it was a cgi app.

Comment: @user: Okay, and what happened when you ran it from the command line, and what is in the server log?

Answer (score 1):

you need to open the file for read/write access.

Note: '+<' will open file for updates. '+>' will overwrite and would defeat what you are attempting.

The following edit should do it:

```
open(REG,"+<$regfile") or fail();
```

Comment: i was able to open and read it ok with "<$regfile" (no + sign). my problem seems to be that it does not recognize that the line already exists still, like I have the code wrong to see if the line is there. each line would look like:  Joe Cool:::12345\r  I tried **eq $find** and also **=~ /$find/** but neither seems to recognize it.

Answer (score -1):

After fixing the less than sign before $regfile i figured out it was simply a typo. I was declaring **@line** but trying to read the array **@lines**. working now. thanks all!

Comment: I wrote exactly that in my own answer.